# PHP structure of a comment database

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I create a blog system with php. The admin can create x posts, and under every post should be a comment function. How can I realize something like that?  I dont know the structure of the databse, because it must be many tables (for each post(?)). Maybe someone of you have a good link. I searched already but have found nothing for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need many tables. You could have a table for the posts like this:

```
id       INT(10)
title    TEXT
content  TEXT
```

And a table for the comments, like this:

```
id       INT(10)
postId   INT(10) // this links to the column post.id
content  TEXT
```

Of course, you can add more columns to both tables if necessary, for example to add timestamps, etc.

Now, when you have a post with id 7, you make sure that all the comments to that post get postId 7. That way, when you display post 7 on your website, you can search for all the rows in the comment table with postId=7, and display exactly those comments that are linked to that post.

I've simplified this example. To optimise the tables you could add indices, primary keys, etc.

Comment: ahh, so I create one table for all comments?

Comment: @Skeptar exactly, with one column that says to which post a comment belongs.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me alot! :)! I've been thinking for a long time, how can i realize that ^^ My last question: professional website, take the same way?

Comment: @Skeptar definitely. This is called a one-to-many relationship (linking many comments to one post). There's also the many-to-many relationship that you could use for example for tags (linking many posts to many tags) which works slightly differently but with the same idea. In a professional website you should always create indices and foreign keys to your tables to optimise your database though. If you google on 'mysql optimalisation', you'll find plenty of explanations about that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the big answer, and the time, that you spend to help me :) You helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

@Skeptar, there quite a number of ways you can achieve this. Let me suggest one to you.

```
Users table: (very obvious)
Columns: user_id (INTEGER(n) PRIMARY KEY), username (VARCHAR(n)), password (VARCHAR(32) for md5), level (INTEGER Example: 1 for admin, 3 for regular user)

Posts:
Columns: post_id (INTEGER(n) PRIMARY KEY), post_title (VARCHAR(n)), post (TEXT), user_id (INTEGER(n))

Comments:
Columns: comment_id (INTEGER(n)), comment(TEXT), post_id,(INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES post(post_ID)) user_id(INTEGER(n) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(user_id))
```

Now, I believe you have a means of allowing both levels (admin and regular) of users to register into your system.

When inserting, you take the post title and the actual post and with the help of some user identification mechanism like `SESSIONS`, you get the user_id and insert them into to post table.

Then for each comment, when inserting, you fetch the post_id of the post on which the user is commenting and insert that into the comment table along with the comment and the user_id.

When you want to fetch all posts, that's fairly easy.

When you want to fetch all comments for a particular post, you take the post_id of that post to the comments table as such:

```
SELECT * FROM comments C, posts P WHERE C.post_id = C.post_id;
```

Since you inserted the user_id against each post and comment, similarly, you can fetch the corresponding user information for each comment as such:

```
SELECT U.username FROM comments C, users U Where C.user_id = U.user_id
```

Remember, this is only to give you and idea and not to be taken as a complete working solution. I wrote this off head and could have some errors.
Also, where I indicated in bracket n (INTEGER(n)), it means you need to replace n with the desired columns size. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow this answer is amazing too! :) Thanks man ! :)